# How to show new window adjacent to mainwindow in QT

Tags: c++, qt

I want to use two GUI windows when I start my appliction. For this, I have implimented Qt Designer Form Class (named it `AnotherWindow`) and implimented the following inside my `MainWindow` constructor:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent),ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    this->setWindowTitle("mainWindow");

    anotherWindow = new AnotherWindow(); // will destroy it in corresponding destructor
    anotherWindow->setWindowTitle("anotherWindow");
    anotherWindow->show();
}
```

The code works correctly and when I run the application, two windows are created (`mainWindow` followed by `anotherWindow`). However, these windows overlap each other when I run the application. Is it possible to display these windows adjacent to each other instead of overlapping? I do not want to drag the overlapped windows adjecent to each other everytime  I run my application. 
I have already looked this question [How to show another window from mainwindow in QT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1518317/how-to-show-another-window-from-mainwindow-in-qt), which wasn't helpful.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51239443/how-to-make-qt-mainwindow-attached-to-each-other??

Comment: Thanks. I will look into it